# Error AH00124 during Symfony 4 server configuration

Tags: symfony, apache2, web-deployment, server-configuration

I currently am trying to deploy my Symfony 4 website on a hosted VPS, I did setup everything quite successfully, installed Apache2, PHP 7.2, MySQL server and phpmyadmin.
I then started configuring my server acordingly to host a Symfony 4 website, and before deploying my own application I tried to deploy a smaller one so that I would know that at least some part worked with a no-database no-bundles application. 
When I try to access my website nothing happens, the following error log is generated in /var/log/apache2 :

```
[Wed Jul 11 14:06:08.580654 2018] [core:error] [pid 13404] [client 37.97.69.85:52997] AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable
 configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.
[Wed Jul 11 14:06:41.901738 2018] [php7:error] [pid 13423] [client 37.97.69.85:44931] PHP Fatal error:
  Uncaught Symfony\\Component\\Dotenv\\Exception\\PathException: Unable to read the "/var/www/releases/20180710151554/public/../.env" environment file.
 in /var/www/releases/20180710151554/vendor/symfony/dotenv/Dotenv.php:54\nStack trace:\n#0 /var/www/releases/20180710151554/public/index.php(15): 
Symfony\\Component\\Dotenv\\Dotenv->load('/var/www/releas...')\n#1 {main}\n  thrown in /var/www/releases/20180710151554/vendor/symfony/dotenv/Dotenv.php on line 54
[Wed Jul 11 14:33:33.702774 2018] [core:error] [pid 13442] [client 37.97.69.85:53026] AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects
 due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.
[Wed Jul 11 14:38:07.055940 2018] [core:error] [pid 13642] [client 37.97.69.85:54628] AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects
 due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.
[Wed Jul 11 14:51:50.406171 2018] [php7:error] [pid 13793] [client 37.97.69.85:55651] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught RuntimeException: 
APP_ENV environment variable is not defined. You need to define environment variables for configuration or add "symfony/dotenv" as a Composer dependency to load variables from a .env file. in /var/www/demo/public/index.php:13\nStack trace:\n#0 {main}\n  thrown in /var/www/demo/public/index.php on line 13
```

I believe this comes from the website configuration file looping somewhere, I have seen cases online where the .htaccess and the configuration file were looping but here I do not have an .htaccess file anywhere as I deleted it.
He is my website configuration :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName vps562960.ovh.net
    ServerAlias vps562960.ovh.net

    DocumentRoot /var/www/releases/20180710151554/public
    <Directory /var/www/releases/20180710151554>
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
        Allow from All

        <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
            Options -MultiViews
            RewriteEngine On
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
            RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
        </IfModule>
    </Directory>

    # uncomment the following lines if you install assets as symlinks
    # or run into problems when compiling LESS/Sass/CoffeeScript assets
    # <Directory /var/www/crvfakeexample.com>
    #     Options FollowSymlinks
    # </Directory>

    # optionally disable the RewriteEngine for the asset directories
    # which will allow apache to simply reply with a 404 when files are
    # not found instead of passing the request into the full symfony stack
    <Directory /var/www/releases/20180710151554/public/bundles>
        <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
            RewriteEngine Off
        </IfModule>
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/vps562960.ovh.net_error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/vps562960.ovh.net_access.log combined

    # optionally set the value of the environment variables used in the application
    #SetEnv APP_ENV prod
    #SetEnv APP_SECRET <app-secret-id>
    #SetEnv DATABASE_URL "mysql://db_user:db_pass@host:3306/db_name"
</VirtualHost>
```

I'm starting to lose hope on deploying that website. Has anyone faced a similar case or do any of you know what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably the problem is that Apache server doesn't set env variables into PHP global array `$_SERVER`. But symfony tries to find env variables exactly in `$_SERVER` array. Either update `public/index.php` and replace all `$_SERVER` with `$_ENV` or uncomment `SetEnv` directives in Apache website conf.